# Laravel MySQL - exibir a quantidade de registros em uma consulta com Join

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, count

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
$empresas = DB::table('empresas')
    ->join('departamentos', 'empresas.id', '=', 'departamentos.empresas_id')
    ->join('eventos', 'eventos.departamentos_empresas_id', '=', 'eventos.id')
    ->select(   'empresas.name as empresa', 'departamentos.name as departamento','eventos.nome as evento' 
    )
    ->get();
```

Que exibe uma tabela com o resultado:

```
Empresa: 1, Departamento:A, Quantidade de Eventos:    , Número de Inscritos:   ,

Empresa: 2, Departamento:A, Quantidade de Eventos:    , Número de Inscritos:   ,

Empresa: 3, Departamento:B, Quantidade de Eventos:    , Número de Inscritos:   ,

Empresa: 4, Departamento:C, Quantidade de Eventos:    , Número de Inscritos:   ,
```

E assim por diante, gostaria de saber como obter a quantidade de eventos e o número de inscritos na mesma query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente fazer algo assim:

```
  $empresas = DB::table('empresas')
                    ->join('departamentos', 'empresas.id', '=', 'departamentos.empresas_id')
                    ->join('eventos', 'eventos.departamentos_empresas_id', '=', 'eventos.id')
                    ->select('empresas.name as empresa', 'departamentos.name as departamento','eventos.nome as evento',
                        DB::raw('COUNT(eventos.departamentos_empresas_id) as qtdeventos')
                    )->get();
```

> DB::raw('COUNT(eventos.departamentos_empresas_id) as qtdeventos')

É para você pegar o COUNT na tabela que vc deseja. Agora é só aplicar na sua Query.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Douglas! De fato, do jeito que você postou funciona, mudando o 'strict' para false, no "config/database". Mas eu gostaria mesmo era de uma forma de exibir os resultados, sem modificar o config/database, porque li que este deveria ser o último recurso, por motivos de segurança.